# R - Checking multiple columns for multiple values - loop

Tags: r, loops

I have a data set with multiple diagnosis columns (ie. DIAG1, DIAG2, DIAG3, etc.). I am looking to create a loop that will check each column for all of my rows, but I'm looking for more than one diagnosis code within each of those columns.

For example, I want to find code xxx1 and xxx3 if present in DIAG1, DIAG2, DIAG3, etc.

My code is below where
1. df = my dataframe
2. df$illness = is the variable I want to create
3. xxxx1 = the code I'm looking for
4. [26:34, 57:72] = the columns where DIAG1, etc. exist

**EDIT:
Example data:

```
DIAG3  DIAG4  DIAG5  DIAG6
1231   xxx1   5468   5468
1454   2352   4542   4864
xxx2   1235   1234   3564
1234   1589   xxx1   8498
```

Code I tried to perform:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
df$illness[i] <- ("xxx1" %in% df[i,26:34, 57:72] | "xxx3" %in% 
df[i,26:34, 57:72]}
```

What I would like my loop to perform:

```
DIAG3  DIAG4  DIAG5  DIAG6  Illness
1231   xxx1   5468   5468   TRUE
1454   2352   4542   4864   FALSE
xxx3   1235   1234   3564   TRUE
1234   1589   xxx1   8498   TRUE
```

What happens is that the code runs but never ends. I don't know where my mistake is. Thank you

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the desired output.

Comment: MrFlick, I added some more information. I hope that helps show what I am trying to perform

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the sub-setting of *df* is wrong. 
It should probably be `df[i,c(26:34,57:72)]`. Is the `df$illness[i]` supposed to be a list?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by looping through the columns, check using `grepl` to create a logical `vector`, then `Reduce` it to a single `vector` with `|`

```
df1$Illness <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1, grepl, pattern = "xxx"))
df1$Illness
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `xxxx1` is actually supposed to be a numeric value, then you could simply use an ifelse statement such as:

```
dat <- data.frame(DIAG3 = c(1231,1454,2222,1234),
                    DIAG4 = c(1111,2352,1235,1589),
                    DIAG5 = c(5468,4542,1234,1111),
                    DIAG6 = c(5468,4864,3564,8498))

library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(Illness = ifelse(DIAG3==1111 | DIAG4==1111 | DIAG5==1111 | DIAG6==1111|
                                    DIAG3==2222 | DIAG4==2222 | DIAG5==2222 | DIAG6==2222, "TRUE", "FALSE"))
```